# Win Up key as Tab key instead Windows Menu

Tags: windows, keyboard, autohotkey, remapping

I would like to modify Windows(Super) key behavour like:

1. {LWin Up} key as Tab character instead Windows Menu.
2. LWin + letter, number, function key etc - works like normal behaviour.(ex: Win + m - minimize)

How to do that at Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$LWin::
    KeyWait LWin, T0.15
    If !ErrorLevel ; if you hold the LWin key for less than 200 miliseconds...
        Send {Tab}
    Else ; but if it is held for more than that...
        Send {LWin Down} ; ...hold LWin down
    KeyWait LWin ; and, in both cases, wait for it to be released
    Send, {LWin Up}
Return
```

This will let you use left Win-key as tab if you shortpress it, and if you hold it down for 0.15 seconds, it will treat the buttonpress as left Win-key and enable you to use Win + letter-shortcuts.

This was crudely stolen and modified from https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/83948-how-to-remap-win-key-and-retain-win-key-other-key-combos/

All credit goes to MasterFocus over there.

Comment: Very interesting behaviour. Sounds promesing. I will test it more in heavy editing :)

Comment: This solution is quite good. It solved my main issue descrbed in this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1294435/how-to-remap-tab-as-win-key-in-autohotkey-so-it-has-two-functions-tab-and-win-mo/1301183#1301183

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 doesn't allow you to change the system default hotkeys. The only way around this is to intercept the keys and make them do something else. You can do this using a tool called [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

I haven't used this tool for a while so I can't give you detailed instructions but you can find a tutorial and some help [on their website](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).